# Better sorting for results

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Results in SO Careers for employers should have sorting by reputation.

Comment: 'Status declined': http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/podcast-76/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was against this, but employers kept asking for it, so I eventually relented.

Employers *can* search by reputation as of a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree - what about a student (or professional) who just found out about SO a month ago?

If you sort by rep alone, you could be excluding new users just because they're new.

Reputation is merely *ONE* indicator of a candidate - you still need to look at their profile, what questions they've answered and asked, etc.